# Removing a character from an ArrayList of characters

Tags: java, list, arraylist, char

I am facing with this unwanted `char` to `int` conversion in a loop. Say I have this List of Characters and I want to remove one of those:

```
List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();
chars.add('a');
chars.add('b');
chars.add('c');
chars.remove('a');  // or chars.remove('a'-'0');
```

so `'a'` is interpreted as its `int` value and I'm getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception. Is there any easy workaround for this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A `char` is promoted to an `int`, which takes precedence over autoboxing, so [`remove(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-) is called instead of [`remove(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) you may have intuitively expect.

You can force the "right" method to be called by boxing the argument yourself:

```
chars.remove(Character.valueOf('a'));
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to cast it to an object type to force the compiler to choose `remove(Object)` instead of `remove(int)`:

```
chars.remove((Character) 'a');
```

Answer (score 6):

You can search through the list for where `a` happens to be.

```
chars.remove(chars.indexOf('a'));
```

Comment: No need for that; you just need to call the right overload.

Comment: Wow I second guessed myself. I initially said to explicitly cast it and then changed my answer.

Comment: I know, but your initial cast was (I believe) wrong.  Casting to the same type has no effect. See my answer.

Comment: I was wrong anyway. I've voted yours as the right answer either way :). Might as well leave this as another way.