# Question on why ArrayList doesnt work here but Hashset does

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, hashset

So, I understand how this algorithm works but I do wonder why this Algorithim doesn't accept ArrayList as a solution and returns an exception:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 112 out of bounds for length 2
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)"
```

The code is:

```
public static int longestSubstring2(String word){
    int pointerA = 0, pointerB = 0, max = 0;
    List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while(pointerB<word.length()){
        if(!list.contains(word.charAt(pointerB))){
            list.add(word.charAt(pointerB));
            pointerB++;
            max = Math.max(max,list.size());

        }else{
           list.remove(word.charAt(pointerA));
            pointerA++;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

If I use a HashSet it works just fine. I understand that it doesn't accept duplicates but how does the arraylist produce an Index 112 out of length 2? Why doesn't an arraylist work with this? Meaning that if I replace `List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();` with a HashSet, it works. Can someone please explain why Hashset works and ArrayList doesnt?

Edit: Answer is another question asked by this user:[Removing a character from an ArrayList of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38861354/removing-a-character-from-an-arraylist-of-characters)

essentially just do this "list.remove(Character.valueOf(word.charAt(pointerA)));"

Comment: It doesn't work because you're removing the item in the loop.

Comment: The remove method of the list interface is overloaded and has 2 versions: The first takes an int as an argument and removes the item at the specific index. The other takes an Object and removes said object from the list. `word.charAt(pointerA)` Will return a primitive `char`. So when you pass that `char` to the `remove` method the actual implementation that is called is the `remove(int index)` method, because a primitive is not an object but `char` can be treated as an `int`.